# Accessing user details in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have a question. I have a blog where users can log in and post or comment something. When they are posting or commenting the text appears with their name as links on the right side(see picture). Now I want to have a userprofile page where the email name etc. are displayed. So I have to grab the name from the first template and use it. Now I can grab their name :) but I don't know how to use them. For example the users name is alex. I can display alex on the new template but what I need is something like that. alex.email or alex.name. Thank you very much.

**view.py**

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request,username):
    return render(request, "user_profile.html",{'username':username})
```

**home.html** this is the template where I want to grab his name

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left mx-auto">
            {% for posts in postmodel_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4 block">
                <a class="overlay" href="{% url 'post_detail' posts.slug  %}"style="text-decoration:none"> </a>
                <div class="card-body inner">
                  <h2 class="card-title">{{ posts.post }}</h2>
                  <p style="text-align:right;" class="card-text text-muted h6"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{%url 'user_profile' posts.author %}">@{{ posts.author }}</a> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>

</div>


<div class="col-md-4 float-right ">
  <button style= "position: fixed; bottom:50px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add New Post</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Post</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>




<style>
.card{
  box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
}
</style>

{%endblock content%}
```

and here I want to have his informations.

**user_profile.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{%load static%}


<div class="card float-left">
  <img src="{% static 'images/img.jpg' %}" alt="John" style="width:100%">
    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
  <h3>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h3>
    <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    {%endif%}
  <p class="title">CEO & Founder, Beehive</p>
  <p>Istanbul Technical University</p
  <p><button>Contact</button></p>
</div>
```

of course now it displays the information of the logged in user but I want to change it depending on which user he clicks[image]

**EDIT**

now I am trying to get two models and the data from the first template to display on the second template with a cbv. Here is my new view.

```
 class UserProfile(ListView):
    template_name = 'user_profile.html'
    model=PostModel
    user=User.objects.get(username=username)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = PostModel.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('created_on')
        context['comments'] = CommentModel.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('created_on')
        context['profile']=user
        return context
```

but here I got the error:
name 'username' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to look the user up, e.g.:

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request, username):
    if request.user.username != username:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    else:
        user = request.user
    return render(request, "user_profile.html", {'profile': user})
```

You'll need to use `{{ profile.username }}` etc. in your template (Django has reserved `{{ user.xxx }}` for itself and will overwrite it.

You should probably add some more permissions to the view. As presented above, any logged in user can view any other logged in user's profile, i.e. change the if to:

```
if request.user.username != username and can_view(request.user, username):
    ....
```

(then implement the `can_view(userobject, username)` function).

Comment: thank you very much and have you an idea how I can provide it in a CBV, I editted it in the question but my main question is to have the data from the template and displaying two other models in the same template

Comment: That is a completely different question. You should ask it as a new question instead of changing the current question (and making any answers unusable for future visitors).

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request, username):
    if request.user.username != username:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    else:
        user = request.user
    posts=PostModel.objects.filter(author=user)
    comments=CommentModel.objects.filter(author=user)
    return render(request, "user_profile.html", {'profile': user,'posts':posts,'comments':comments})
```

I solved my problem so and I am happy :)